# Git Large file system is not able to upload the files more than 5GB

Tags: git, tfs, git-lfs, tfvc

I am trying to migrate the repository from TFVC to Git with History.
I am using `git tfs` to clone it from a branch of a repo from TFVC to my local and trying to push it to a empty Git repository by enabling `git lfs` to track the large files and upload.

But I am getting error like : **! [remote rejected]       master -> master (TF402462: This push was rejected because its size is greater than the 5120 MB limit for pushes in this repository. Learn more at https://aka.ms/gitlimit)**

Steps:
Cloned a TFVC repo branch locally using:

```
git tfs clone http://myTfsServer:8080/tfs/TfsRepository $/ProjectName/ProjectBranch
```

I cloned a empty git repo and
I added the branch files with history to that git repo from TFVC repo
Ex:
git remote add origin `'*URL of the empty git repo*'`

Enabled LFS

Tracked the Large files

Made a commit &
Trying to push it using `git push origin -u -all`

I am unable to identify where I am going wrong, everytime its giving me error saying cannot upload more than 5120 MB. Am I doing any mistake using **git lfs**? Or what is this error?

Comment: Any suggestions will be really helpful please !!!

Comment: Did you ensure that the blobs were removed from your Git repository by running `git lfs migrate`?

Comment: @DanielMann Did you mean I need to ensure to remove the blobs from the empty Git repo or the existing TFVC repo?

Comment: Did you look up the `git lfs migrate` command and look at what it does? That answers your question.